Accessing. Net application hosted on azure
We have a self contained .net application running on a pool of windows 2019 azure vms. Currently users are accessing the app via citrix xen desktops with published apps.
Our support contract with citrix is over and we need a new method for the users accessing the apps.
I'm eager to hear people's suggestions on a replacement for citrix. Many thanks

You want to look at Azure Virtual Desktop
